# How to implement custom UIView with lazy/dynamic loading of subviews, similar to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, lazy-loading

So, I currently have a GridView class, which is essentially what it sounds like.  It is a subclass of UIView that has a staging area that has a bunch of subviews placed in a grid-like manner.  Currently I place the GridView into a UIScrollView in the nib.  When the GridView loads, it has to load all of the subviews at once, even the ones that are not visible.

For example, if I have a grid with 5 columns and 500 rows, it will load all 2500 views at once, which as you can imagine, take a long time.  I would like to implement it so that it only loads the views that are visibile, and as the user scrolls, load the the new views.  This is similar to how UITableView loads its cells.

I assume it will follow the same pattern as UITableView, but I'm not quite sure on how to get started.  Anyone have any pointers/tips?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You know the size of each grid cell. I assume you are implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, so you can receive a message when scrolling occurs. So, once you get the `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)` message, calculate the visible cells, and load the views for the cells come into view.

Better yet, just like in `UITableView`, recycle your cell views. As cells go out of view (top or bottom), use the cells that went out of view for the new cells coming into view.

Look at the ivars and methods of the `UITableView` class, and think about mimicking that behavior and implementation.